# How do I turn a list into a string

Tags: python

I have written a code that ends up outputting what I want but in list format. Just to make it easier to understand, I will make up an input.

If I get

```python
>>>
['H','e','l','l','o',' ','W','o','r','l','d']
```

as an output, how can I change it to:

```python
>>>
'Hello World'
```

I have tried using `.join()` but it tells me that it does not work with lists as an error code.

If you need any more information, or I am being vague, just leave a comment saying so and I will update the question.

And if you leave a downvote, can you at least tell me why so that I can fix it or know what to improve for later posts

Comment: `join` is a method on `str`: `''.join(iterable)`

Comment: `join` does work. Also questions on this site should be well-researched, which I argue this one isn’t.

Answer (score 4):

You `join` on the connector like this: `''.join(['H','e','l','l','o',' ','W','o','r','l','d'])`

Answer (score 1):

Just use `join` method by passing a list as **parameter**.

```
str = ''.join(['H','e','l','l','o',' ','W','o','r','l','d'])
```